# Numbers not displaying on iPhone / ios

Tags: html, ios, css, phone-number

So I'm trying to create a small contact section which includes a phone number but it won't show up when I view it on my iPhone, although it shows on desktop (even if I shrink the screen smaller than my iPhone). **(tested on Chrome and Safari for desktop)** *(see picture)*

[image]

The text shows if there is only a few numbers or only letters, but disappears with any more. *(see picture)*

[image]

The numbers are obviously still there (although invisible), because if I press on where they are supposed to be, it highlights the text. *(see picture)*

[image]

If I keep on holding down, then it asks if I want to call the number. *(see picture)*

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
<div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-us">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <div>
            <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Munich, Germany</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Testing 123 testing</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>someone@example.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="private-hire">
        <h3>Private Hire</h3>
        <p class="body-copy-mobile">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute iruredolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: check the button title text color.

Comment: it may be you are not setting color in "fa fa-phone" class

Comment: I just tried setting the color, even with a very specific selector. Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that IOS automatically changes a phone number color to white and a bit bold. You also have to select it as an achor (a) tag. Here was my fix:

```
.contact-us a {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```